# Telegram бот Python ответ на inline button

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Продолжаю разбираться с ботом для телеграм, и возник следующий вопрос.

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, выходил последующий текст с другой кнопкой. Руинится при запуске, что я сделала не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

P.S. Файл с константами сделала отдельным если что.

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Click', 
callback_data='add')
markup.add(button)
bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, 
text='Text',reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
if call.data == 'add':
    key = types.InlineKeyboardButton(row_width=1)
    url = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="URL", url="")
    key.add(url)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Text', 
reply_markup=key)

if __name__ == '__main__':
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения!

В своем же коде нашла кучу ошибок.

1. key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
2. Табуляция. Если увидите ошибки, связанные с табуляцией, то если вы пользователь Sublime Text, зайдите: View --> Indentation --> Convert Indentation to Tabs